# there is a SQL syntax error when i use update and set with case

Tags: mysql

I have syntax error in my SQL console and I cant find the main error in my SQL queries.

```
UPDATE con_info
SET profession =
CASE
WHEN programmer = 'Y' THEN 'programmer',
WHEN teacher = 'Y' THEN 'teacher',
WHEN seller= 'Y' THEN 'seller',
END;
```

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images.

Comment: Look at the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) when getting syntax errors. Attention to detail is an important part of programming. Text format questions are better received on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `comma(,)` from the case when part

```
Update con_info 
set profession= case when Programmer='Y' then 'Programmer'
                     when teachet='Y' then 'Teacher'
                     when Seller='Y' then 'Seller' End
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm coding with a mysql book and i think syntaxes are old in that book. This one works.